# Declaring a new node but doesn't equals NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

void insert(node * root, node * newnode)
{
if (root != NULL)
{
    cout<<"Here1"<<endl;
    if (root->data > newnode->data)
        if (root->left != NULL)
            insert(root->left,newnode);
        else
            root->left = newnode;
    else
        if (root->right != NULL)
            insert(root->right,newnode);
        else
            root->right = newnode;
    return;
}
else
    root = newnode;
}

void inorder(node * root)
{
if (root != NULL)
{
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<endl;
    inorder(root->right);
}
}

node * newn(int ele)
{
    node *newnode = new node();
    newnode->left = NULL;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    newnode->data = ele;
    return newnode;
}

int main(void)
{
int ele,choice = 0;
node *root = new node();
while(choice != 5)
{
    cout<<"1. Enter\n"
           "2. Inorder\n"
           "3. PreOrder\n"
           "4. PostOrder\n"
           "5. Exit\n";
    cin>>choice;    
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: cout<<"\nElement : ";
                cin>>ele;
                insert(root,newn(ele));
                break;
        ....
```

This is a code for binary search tree in c++. Its only the insertion part. And the inorder printing function.

When I create 3 nodes, and then try to print inorder, it shows initially a zero. And for testing this I tried to print "here", and it seems when I declare a root node pointer and it is not equal to NULL. I don't seem to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

In the `insert` function the argument `root` is passed by value, which means the pointer is copied and inside the function you only have the copy. Changing a copy will of course not change the original.

You need to pass the pointer *by reference*:

```
void insert(node *& root, node * newnode)
```

If you spent a minute of debugging you would easily have found this out yourself.

Comment: It would be less confusing to do `node* insert(node* root, node * newnode)` and then `root = insert(root,newn(ele));`

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the mistake by equating the root to NULL as

```
node *root = new node();
root = NULL;
```

at the time of initialization. No need for the passing by reference was needed, because if an argument is passed by reference it automatically passes a pointer(referencing to that object) to that function. But in my case, since I am already passing a pointer, there no need to pass the pointer by reference.